# How to manage shadowing in Mapstruct

Tags: mapstruct

```
public abstract class CaseDTOBase{

       private Integer version;

       public static void mapFromCaseToCaseDTO(Fall fall, CaseDTOBase caseDTOBase) {
        caseDTOBase.setVersion(fall.getVersion());}
       }
    }

public class AufCaseDTO extends CaseDTOBase{

  private Integer version;

  public static AufCaseDTO from(AufFall aufFall, Fall fallGemeldetAnPKR) {

  AufCaseDTO aufCaseDTO = AufCaseDTO.builder().version(aufFall.getVersion()).build();

  CaseDTOBase.mapFromCaseToCaseDTO(aufFall.getFall(), aufCaseDTO);

  return aufCaseDTO;
 }
}
```

*As you can see the one variable uses aufFall.getVersion() and the another version variable uses aufFall.getFall().getVersion(), I cannot add both inside of MapStruct because it says that it does not allow duplicates. How can I make this in MapStruct?*

```
    @Mapping(target = "version", source = "aufFall.version")  
    @Mapping(target = "version", source = "aufFall.fall.version")

    @Mapping(target = "pksamAufFallDTO", source = "aufFall")
    AufCaseDTO from(AufFall aufFall, Fall fallGemeldetAnPKR);
```

Comment: There's only one version? What is it you try to achieve? Should `aufFall.version` be mapped or the alternative `aufVall.fall.version`.

Comment: Both should be mapped. This is shadowing of a variable in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapStruct does not support using the same `target` property in multiple mappings. To achieve what you are looking for you'll have to write your own method for it.

e.g.

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "version", source = "aufFall", qualifiedByName = "aufFallToVersion")
    @Mapping(target = "pksamAufFallDTO", source = "aufFall")
    AufCaseDTO from(AufFall aufFall, Fall fallGemeldetAnPKR);

    @Named("aufFallToVersion")
    default Integer toVersion(AufFall AufFall) {
        if (aufFall == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (aufFall.getVersion() != null) {
            return aufFall.getVersion();
        } else if (aufFall.getFall() != null && aufFall.getFall().getVersion() != null) {
            return aufFall.getFall().getVersion();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Filip this will work for me I think. I couldnt put "vote" because I dont have so much rights.

Comment: You don't have to vote, but you can accept the answer. You have the rights for that, since you asked the question :)